# Import Existing Python App into AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I need to create an AWS Lambda version of an existing Python 2.7 program written by someone else who has left the company.

Using one function I need to convert as an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from aws_common import get_profiles,get_regions
from aws_ips import get_all_public_ips
import sys

def main(cloud_type):
    # csv header
    output_header = "profile,region,public ip"

    profiles = get_profiles(cloud_type)
    regions = get_regions(cloud_type)

    print output_header

    for profile in profiles:
        for region in regions:
            # public_ips = get_public_ips(profile,region)
            public_ips = get_all_public_ips(profile,region)

            for aws_ip in public_ips:
                print "%s,%s,%s" % (profile,region,aws_ip)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cloud_type = 'commercial'
    if sys.argv[1]:
        if sys.argv[1] == 'govcloud':
            cloud_type = 'govcloud'

    main(cloud_type)
```

I need to know how to create this as an AWS handler with event and context arguments from the code above.

If I could get some pointers on how to do this it would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you offering a job? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply start writing python function inside the handler of aws labda.

in handler simply start defining functions and variables and uplaod zip file inside lambda if there is any type of dependency.

you can change the python version in lambda as per if you are using python 2.7.

i would like to suggest [server less](https://serverless.com/) framework and uplaoding your code to lambda. it's so easy to manage dependency code management from locally.

here you are using aws_common and importing you have to check it is inside aws sdk or not.

you can import aws-sdk and use it

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');  

exports.handler =  function (event, context) 
{  

}
```

inside exports handler you can start making for loops in python or goes further

Comment: OK thank you for that explanation! The program I need to get working in AWS Lambda consists of a lot of files. Would I need to have handlers in each of the files? Or do I just need a handler for the main function in the main file?

Comment: handler work as main function aws invoke function using handler . you can read more at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

Comment: if it's lots of file you can make different lambda function and your application will be server less application